# Kotlin. Unchecked cast: Any? to HashMap<String?, String?>?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get `HashMap<String?, String?>?` from `firebaseDatabase`:

```
override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    val users: HashMap<String?, String?>? = dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String?, String?>?  // todo !!!
    if (users != null) {
        if (!users.containsKey(userUid)) {
            users[userUid] = userName
        }
    }
}
```

This code works but `Android Studio` shows a warning on a 2nd line:

```
 Unchecked cast: Any? to HashMap<String?, String?>?
```

How to fix this in a proper way?

Comment: and whats type of dataSnapshot.value?

Comment: maybe use   
`getValue(GenericTypeIndicator<T> t)`

Comment: @AntonKazakov it's "Any?"

Comment: @Rainmaker so what's wrong?:) you can use suppress warning for unchecked cast. And btw you can omit : HashMap<String?, String?>?

Comment: @AntonKazakov I'd like to implement it in a safe way. What if someone changes data in firebase. I tried to check if it is Hashmap<String, String> but it doesn't work too

Comment: What should happen if `value` isn't a `HashMap<String?, String?>?`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach with `GenericTypeIndicator` works, thank you @leoderprofi

```
    val ti = object : GenericTypeIndicator<HashMap<String?, String?>?>() {}
    //...
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val users: HashMap<String?, String?>? = dataSnapshot.getValue(ti)
        if (users != null) {
            if (!users.containsKey(userUid)) {
                users[userUid] = userName
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is from the GenericTypeIndicator?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`

(eg)

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
val users: HashMap<String?, String?>? = dataSnapshot.value as HashMap<String?, String?>?
```