# How to solve warning Unchecked cast android studio?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have warning:

```
Unchecked cast: Serializable! to kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, String> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, String> */
```

at this place:

```
filterData = bundle.getSerializable("filter_data") as HashMap<String, String>
```

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51805648/unchecked-cast-java-io-serializable-to-java-util-arraylist) this question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209150/kotlin-unchecked-cast-any-to-hashmapstring-string) one but I didn't manage to solve my problem. I have to get data by bundle at fragments. Maybe someone had similar problem and knows how to solve it?

### UPDATE

I have this global variable:

```
 var filterData: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
```

how I receive it due to comments and answers:

```
 when {
       bundle.containsKey("filter_data") -> {
       val serializable = bundle.getSerializable("filter_data")
       if(serializable is java.util.HashMap<*, *>){
         filterData = bundle.getSerializable("filter_data") as HashMap<String, String>
         Singleton.filter_data = filterData
         getJobList(offset, type, sp.getString("access_token", ""), bundle.getSerializable("filter_data") as HashMap<String, String>, false)
         }

      }
....
}
```

and I have this `as HashMap<String, String>` part yellow and warning:

```
Unchecked cast: Serializable! to kotlin.collections.HashMap<String, String> /* = java.util.HashMap<String, String> */
```

Comment: the warning says that `bundle.getSerializable("filter_data")` could be any `Serializable`. That's why it is your responsibility to cast it, as it is not possible to check at compile time. To remove warning, you can do like `var serializable = bundle.getSerializable("filter_data"); if(serializable  is HashMap<String, String>) {filterData  = serializable  as HashMap<String, String> }`

Comment: AS suggested me to check serializable at if condition as `if(serializable is HashMap<*, *>)`  and I decided to ask you about what I have to do in this situation?

Comment: ok, but I'm not sure what you mean in your comment. Did my comment help, or you still have a problem?

Comment: I still have the problem :(

Comment: ok, and what is the problem you still have?

Comment: the problem is that I tried to use your comment but I failed to use `if` condition, and as a result all your comment can't be used, I also didn't manage to solve my problem with the solutions from answers below my question

Comment: `I failed to use if condition` why? What is a problem?

Comment: Concerning your updated code: You should use the `val serializable` you extracted before the `if` expression to continue and not call `bundle.getSerializable` again.

Comment: @LPeteR90, no :) I have this warning when I'm trying to get data by bundle at my fragment

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [safe cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) to get an optional value from your bundle like

```
filterData = bundle.getSerializable("filter_data") as? HashMap<String, String>
```

So your `filterData` would be of type `HashMap<String, String>?`. In case the cast would fail, `filterData` would be null and you would have to handle that case.

Comment: it didn't help me, I did all you said with my variables

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply @Vladyslav Matviienko solution like following.

```
var filterData = bundle.getSerializable("filter_data") as HashMap<*, *>
```